# Is there a way in Keras to immediately stop training?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am writing a custom early stopping callback for my `tf.keras` training. For that I can set the variable `self.model.stop_training = True` in one of the callback functions, like for example `on_epoch_end()`. However, Keras stops the training only when the current epoch is done, even if I set this variable within the training of one epoch, for example in `on_batch_end()`.

Hence my question: Is there a way in Keras to stop training immediately, even within the progress of the current epoch?

Comment: I know a way, but you're not going to like it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `model.stop_training` parameter to stop the training.

For example, if we want to stop the training at 2nd epochs 3rd batch then you can do something like below.

```
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.optimizers import SGD
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

class My_Callback(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def on_epoch_begin(self, epoch, logs={}):
      self.epoch = epoch

    def on_batch_end(self, batch, logs={}):
        if self.epoch == 1 and batch == 3:
          print (f"\nStopping at Epoch {self.epoch}, Batch {batch}")
          self.model.stop_training = True


X_train = np.random.random((100, 3))
y_train = pd.get_dummies(np.argmax(X_train[:, :3], axis=1)).values

clf = Sequential()
clf.add(Dense(9, activation='relu', input_dim=3))
clf.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
clf.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=SGD())

clf.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=16, callbacks=[My_Callback()])
```

Output:

```
Epoch 1/10
100/100 [==============================] - 0s 337us/step - loss: 1.0860
Epoch 2/10
 16/100 [===>..........................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.0830
Stopping at Epoch 1, Batch 3
<keras.callbacks.callbacks.History at 0x7ff2e3eeee10>
```

Answer (score 2):

In keras you use [`EarlyStopping`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/callbacks/callbacks.py#LC733) to stop when a monitored quantity has stopped improving. From your question it is not clear what the condition is you want to stop. If you just want to monitor a value like in `EarlyStopping` but only want to stop after a batch, if the value is not improving, you can just rewrite the `EarlyStopping` class and implement the logic in `on_batch_end` instead of `on_epoch_end`:

```
class EarlyBatchStopping(Callback):


    def __init__(self,
                 monitor='val_loss',
                 min_delta=0,
                 patience=0,
                 verbose=0,
                 mode='auto',
                 baseline=None,
                 restore_best_weights=False):
        super(EarlyStopping, self).__init__()

        self.monitor = monitor
        self.baseline = baseline
        self.patience = patience
        self.verbose = verbose
        self.min_delta = min_delta
        self.wait = 0
        self.stopped_epoch = 0
        self.restore_best_weights = restore_best_weights
        self.best_weights = None

        if mode not in ['auto', 'min', 'max']:
            warnings.warn('EarlyStopping mode %s is unknown, '
                          'fallback to auto mode.' % mode,
                          RuntimeWarning)
            mode = 'auto'

        if mode == 'min':
            self.monitor_op = np.less
        elif mode == 'max':
            self.monitor_op = np.greater
        else:
            if 'acc' in self.monitor:
                self.monitor_op = np.greater
            else:
                self.monitor_op = np.less

        if self.monitor_op == np.greater:
            self.min_delta *= 1
        else:
            self.min_delta *= -1

    def on_train_begin(self, logs=None):
        # Allow instances to be re-used
        self.wait = 0
        self.stopped_epoch = 0
        if self.baseline is not None:
            self.best = self.baseline
        else:
            self.best = np.Inf if self.monitor_op == np.less else -np.Inf

    def on_batch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        current = self.get_monitor_value(logs)
        if current is None:
            return

        if self.monitor_op(current - self.min_delta, self.best):
            self.best = current
            self.wait = 0
            if self.restore_best_weights:
                self.best_weights = self.model.get_weights()
        else:
            self.wait += 1
            if self.wait >= self.patience:
                self.stopped_epoch = epoch
                self.model.stop_training = True
                if self.restore_best_weights:
                    if self.verbose > 0:
                        print('Restoring model weights from the end of '
                              'the best epoch')
                    self.model.set_weights(self.best_weights)

    def on_train_end(self, logs=None):
        if self.stopped_epoch > 0 and self.verbose > 0:
            print('Epoch %05d: early stopping' % (self.stopped_epoch + 1))

    def get_monitor_value(self, logs):
        monitor_value = logs.get(self.monitor)
        if monitor_value is None:
            warnings.warn(
                'Early stopping conditioned on metric `%s` '
                'which is not available. Available metrics are: %s' %
                (self.monitor, ','.join(list(logs.keys()))), RuntimeWarning
            )
        return monitor_value
```

If you have another logic, you can use `on_batch_end` and set `self.model.stop_training = True` based on your logic, but I think you got the idea.

Comment: The link to the EarlyStopping documentation is broken. I think this would be [the repaired EarlyStopping link](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/EarlyStopping).