# How can I use Keras Custom Callback stopping function for batches

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, callback

I am training on a very large dataset. It takes almost 1.5 hours to train a single epoch. The accuracy reaches a desired level is almost constant within the first few minutes. But I cant stop training using callback function on_batch_end, since it is stopping only after one epoch.  Can anyone help me with this?

```
acc_thresh = 0.965

class myCallback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback): 
    def on_train_batch_end(self, batch, logs={}): 
        if(logs.get('accuracy') > acc_thresh):   
          print("\nWe have reached %2.2f%% accuracy, so we will stopping training." %(acc_thresh*100))   
          self.model.stop_training = True
```

It continues even after reaching the limit and outputting the message "reached 96.5% accuracy".  Any Idea on how to stop training in-between batches (and not between epochs) ?

Comment: Did you try `break` keyword?

Comment: `self.model.stop_training = True` should be inside the `if` right?

Comment: In `keras 2.3.1` it seems to work - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62172076/2047442). I tested it in `tf.keras` and it doesn't work - see [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1oFmpROh8V5esf74nI9FNBvebBi3Vpv4u?usp=sharing). But you may add `sys.exit()` to actually halt training.

Comment: But I tried to use with keras 2.4.  not working with that